# How to do left outer joins with DbLinq and SQLite?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sqlite, left-join, dblinq

I tried

```
db.Table1.GroupJoin(db.Table2,
    t1 => t1.Id,
    t2 => t2.t1Id,
    (t1,g) => new { t1, g })
  .Where(item => !item.g.Any())
  .Select(item => item.t1);
```

But it returned 0 results. I'm trying to write something that generated the following SQL code (or something similar)

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 as t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 as t2
ON t1.Id = t2.t1Id
WHERE IsNull(t2.Id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your desired result is to identify the items from `Table1` that had no results during the left outer join with `Table2`.

In fluent notation, the approach would be similar to this:

```
var query = db.Table1.GroupJoin(db.Table2,
                t1 => t1.Id,
                t2 => t2.t1Id,
                (t1, joined) => new { t1, joined }
            )
            .SelectMany(r => r.joined.DefaultIfEmpty(), (r, j) => new  
            {
                r.t1, 
                j
            })
            .Where(r => r.j == null)
            .Select(r => r.t1);
```

In query syntax:

```
var query = from t1 in db.Table1
            join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.Id equals t2.t1Id into joined
            from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where j == null
            select t1;
```